# Custom marker bitmap error Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap

Tags: java, android, google-maps, bitmap, android-bitmap

I'm using the firebase realtime database to get some users info and show a custom marker for each one.. to set the icon for the marker options I use the method below and it works for most cases.

But more often the app crashes when creating the bitmap of the custom view for the marker..! Is there a way to improve the method and prevent bitmap problems.!

**Code**

```
  { // other methods.. 

    private void showMarker() {

    BitmapDescriptor pin = BitmapDescriptorFactory
        .fromBitmap(getMarkerBitmapFromView(data.getUserAvatar()));
        userMarker = googleMap.addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
            .position(latLng)
            .title(data.getName() + "")
            .snippet(data.getSectionName() + "")
            .icon(pin));
      }

       // I take pic url from firebase and show it into the marker view
      private Bitmap getMarkerBitmapFromView(String ImgUrl) {
        if (getActivity() != null) {

          View customMarkerView = ((LayoutInflater) getActivity().getSystemService(Context.LAYOUT_INFLATER_SERVICE)).inflate(R.layout.map_marker, null);
          CircleImageView markerImageView = customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.pic_user);
          FrameLayout pin = customMarkerView.findViewById(R.id.marker);
          pin.setBackground(ContextCompat.getDrawable(getActivity(), R.drawable.map_marker_green));

           Picasso.with(getActivity())
             .load(ImgUrl)
             .resize(80, 80)
             .error(R.drawable.user_dummy)
             .placeholder(R.drawable.user_dummy)
             .into(markerImageView);

          customMarkerView.measure(MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
          customMarkerView.layout(0, 0, customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight());
          customMarkerView.buildDrawingCache(true);

          Bitmap returnedBitmap = Bitmap.createBitmap(customMarkerView.getMeasuredWidth(), customMarkerView.getMeasuredHeight(), Config.ARGB_8888);

          Canvas canvas = new Canvas(returnedBitmap);
          canvas.drawColor(Color.WHITE, Mode.SRC_IN);
          Drawable drawable = customMarkerView.getBackground();
          if (drawable != null) {
            drawable.draw(canvas);
          }
          customMarkerView.draw(canvas);
          return returnedBitmap;
        } else {
         // the crash didn't happen because of this! I've checked using breakpoints, it returns bitmap 99.9% of times.
          return null; 
        }
      }

    }
```

**The Error**

```
E/AndroidRuntime: FATAL EXCEPTION: main
    Process: com.arapeak.katateeb, PID: 30706
    com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.common.apiexception.b: Failed to decode image. The provided image must be a Bitmap.
    at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.k.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12529020@12.5.29 (040308-192802242):5)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.o.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12529020@12.5.29 (040308-192802242):7)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.db.<init>(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12529020@12.5.29 (040308-192802242):25)
   at com.google.maps.api.android.lib6.impl.bc.a(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12529020@12.5.29 (040308-192802242):496)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.l.onTransact(:com.google.android.gms.dynamite_dynamitemodulesb@12529020@12.5.29 (040308-192802242):94)
   at android.os.Binder.transact(Binder.java:387)
   at com.google.android.gms.internal.zzeu.zza(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.internal.zzg.addMarker(Unknown Source)
   at com.google.android.gms.maps.GoogleMap.addMarker(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: Start to catch the exception so your app will not crash.

Comment: `more often the app crashes when creating the bitmap `. It does not look like that. Then if so then tell which statement of your code produces the exception. It looks more that somewhere else, where the bitmap is used, you have problems.

Comment: @greenapps the crash in the code points to the line where I start instantiate the marker `userMarker = googleMap.addMa.....` , but it didn't make sense to me.

Comment: Indeed. That is what i tried to tell you. Not during creation of the bitmap but during using it by addMarker().

Comment: @greenapps why do you think the reason for this? is there a workaround to this?

Comment: You even call addMarker() if getMarkerBitmapFromView/) returns null. Not a good idea i think. And catch that exception!

Comment: `Picasso.with(.....` Is that a synchronous or asynchronous function?

Comment: less often `getActivity()` can be null and I don't why maybe the fragment wasn't attached successfully but for that I had to check and if it's null I reuten the bitmap as null, should check if bitmap is null before creating the  marker?

Comment: I guess so, it's famous image loading library https://github.com/square/picasso

Comment: What do you guess so???? You should answer the question. Make a choice! What is it?

Comment: OK, it is.! does it have anything to do with issue at hand?

Comment: It is? What is it? ??? Which of the two is it? Synchronous or asynchronous?

Comment: I meant it's asynchronous.

Comment: If so then your code cannot get the right icon. As it is not yet there when you try to grab it. But a wrong icon will not let your app crash. Handle the null that can be returned. And catch exceptions. Post your updated code.

Comment: can you elaborate more please, because it does work most of the time and loads the pic url into the imageview.!

Comment: Adapt your code first. Update your post.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Hi I have used like this and it's working fine for me

```
//generate bit map from view
private Bitmap createBitMap(View v) {
    Bitmap b = Bitmap.createBitmap(v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight(), Bitmap.Config.ARGB_8888);
    if (b != null) {
        Canvas c = new Canvas(b);
        v.layout(0, 0, v.getMeasuredWidth(), v.getMeasuredHeight());
        v.draw(c);
    }
    return b;
}

// created user marker with his image
private void addMyLocationMarker() {

View view = DataBindingUtil.inflate(getActivity().getLayoutInflater(), R.layout.layout_marker, null, false);
view.setLayoutParams(new ViewGroup.LayoutParams(RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT, RelativeLayout.LayoutParams.WRAP_CONTENT));
view.measure(View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(view.getWidth(), View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED), View.MeasureSpec.makeMeasureSpec(0, View.MeasureSpec.UNSPECIFIED));
view.layout(0, 0, view.getMeasuredWidth(), view.getMeasuredHeight()); 
    if (userMarker != null)
        userMarker = googleMap
                .addMarker(new MarkerOptions()
                        .anchor(0.5F, 0.5F)
                        .position(latlng)
                        .icon(BitmapDescriptorFactory.fromBitmap(createBitMap(bindingUserMarker.getRoot()))));
        userMarker.setZIndex(2f);
        updateUserMarkerImage(view);
    }
}

//update user image
private void updateUserMarkerImage(View view ) {
   ImageView imageView=view.findViewById(R.id.image);
    //load your image using any image loader and recreate marker with your view and set it marker
}
```